# The range projection of product of projections

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let  $p$ be a projection in $A$. Suppose that $e$ is a finite projection. Can we determine all types of vn-algebras in which   $p-p\wedge(1-e)$ is a finite projection?

Rem. It seems that when  $A=B(H)$, the range of the projection  $p-p\wedge(1-e)$ 
is just $\overline{peH}$ which is clearly finite dimentional subspace, since $e$ is  a finite
 projection.

Comment: Does finiteness of projection $e\in B(H)$ imply that $e(H)$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: I have also another one which probably you have an idea about. Let's consider projections $p,q$ with $p\leq q$. For a given a projection $e$, can we say that $q\wedge e-p\wedge e\leq q-p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parallelogram rule in "Murray-von Numann equivalency" we have $p-p\wedge(1-e)\sim e-e\wedge(1-p)$. Hence, $p-p\wedge(1-e)$ is always finite, if $e$ is finite.